# How to repeat values in a table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table in Microsoft SQL Server that logged some values on data change triggers. Now, in order to display some graphs, I would like to get (or repeat) a value per 10 minutes from each column(for example).

I would try to avoid, if possible, an INSERT command modifying the table itself.

Original table:

```
Time Stamp---- | A | B | C |
---------------+---+---+---+
01-01-19 10:20 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
01-01-19 15:30 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
01-01-19 22:50 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
02-01-19 01:40 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
...
```

Result I would like to achieve:

```
Time Stamp---- | A | B | C |
---------------+---+---+---+
01-01-19 10:20 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
01-01-19 10:30 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
01-01-19 10:40 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
01-01-19 10:50 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
... 
01-01-19 15:30 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
01-01-19 15:40 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
01-01-19 15:50 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
01-01-19 16:00 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
...
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your dates are mm-dd-yy and times are hh:mm...

```
create table #Original (
    [Time Stamp----] datetime2,
    A int,
    B int,
    C int
)

insert #Original
values ({ts '2019-01-01 10:20:00.000'}, 1, 0, 0)
     , ({ts '2019-01-01 15:30:00.000'}, 0, 0, 1)
     , ({ts '2019-01-01 22:50:00.000'}, 0, 1, 0)
     , ({ts '2019-01-02 01:40:00.000'}, 1, 0, 0)

;
with 
boundaries as (
    select min(o.[Time Stamp----]) as s
    , dateadd(minute, 10, max(o.[Time Stamp----])) as e
    from #Original o
),
timeslist as (
    select 1 as i
    , (select s from boundaries) as s
    , (select s from boundaries) as d

    union all
    select t.i + 1
    , t.s
    , dateadd(minute, 10, d)
    from timeslist t
    where d < (select e from boundaries)
),
result as (
    select 
      right('0' + cast(MONTH(t.d) as varchar(2)), 2) + '-' + 
      right('0' + cast(DAY(t.d) as varchar(2)), 2) + '-' + 
      right('0' + cast(year(t.d) % 100 as varchar(2)), 2) + ' ' + 
      right('0' + cast(datepart(hour, t.d) as varchar(2)), 2) + ':' + 
      right('0' + cast(datepart(minute, t.d) as varchar(2)), 2) as 'Time Stamp----'
    , o2.A
    , o2.B
    , o2.C

    from timeslist t
      inner join (
        select o.[Time Stamp----]
        , o.A
        , o.B
        , o.C
        , lead (o.[Time Stamp----], 1, dateadd(minute, 10, o.[Time Stamp----])) over (order by o.[Time Stamp----]) as OldTs
        from #Original o
      ) o2 on o2.[Time Stamp----] <= t.d and o2.OldTs > t.d
)

select *
from result
order by [Time Stamp----]


drop table #Original
```

Answer (score 0):

```
To select records with manufactured duplicates, try

    SELECT Dateadd(mi, DQ.T,TimeStamp) as 'TimeStamp', A, B, C From YourTable 
        CROSS JOIN (Select 0 T UNION ALL 
                    Select 10 T UNION ALL 
                    Select 20 T UNION ALL 
                    Select 30 T) DQ
```

or to insert duplicates, try

```
INSERT YourTable 
    SELECT Dateadd(mi, DQ.T,TimeStamp) as 'TimeStamp', A, B, C From YourTable 
        CROSS JOIN (
                    Select 10 T UNION ALL 
                    Select 20 T UNION ALL 
                    Select 30 T) DQ
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I recommend maling a "Time Table", but i do this on the fly here using a Tally. Anyway, I *think* this is what you're after?

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable ([timestamp] datetime2(0), --This is a bad name for a column, as timestamp means soemthing else in SQL Server
                            A bit,
                            B bit,
                            C bit);
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable ([timestamp],
                           A,
                           B,
                           C)
VALUES ('2019-01-01T10:20:00',1,0,0),
       ('2019-01-01T15:30:00',0,0,1),
       ('2019-01-01T22:50:00',0,1,0),
       ('2019-01-02T01:40:00',1,0,0);

GO

WITH N AS
    (SELECT N
     FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP(144) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1 AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3),
Times AS(
    SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE,T.I * 10,CONVERT(time(0),'00:00:00')) AS TimeSlot
    FROM Tally T),
DateTimes AS(
    SELECT DISTINCT
           CONVERT(datetime,CONVERT(date,YT.[timestamp])) + CONVERT(datetime,T.TimeSlot) AS DateTimeSlot
    FROM dbo.YourTable YT
         CROSS JOIN Times T),
Groups AS(
    SELECT DT.DateTimeSlot,
           CONVERT(tinyint,YT.A) AS A, --Can't aggregate Bits
           CONVERT(tinyint,YT.B) AS B,
           CONVERT(tinyint,YT.C) AS C,
           COUNT(YT.A) OVER (ORDER BY DT.DateTimeSlot ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Grp
    FROM DateTimes DT
         LEFT JOIN dbo.YourTable YT ON DT.DateTimeSlot = YT.[timestamp])
SELECT G.DateTimeSlot,
       MAX(G.A) OVER (PARTITION BY G.Grp) AS A,
       MAX(G.B) OVER (PARTITION BY G.Grp) AS B,
       MAX(G.C) OVER (PARTITION BY G.Grp) AS C
FROM Groups G
ORDER BY G.DateTimeSlot;

GO

DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**SQL RECURSION**](https://www.sql-workbench.eu/comparison/recursive_queries.html) and **CROSS JOIN**

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e83f7/1/0)

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=178a9aea4db935d473f2eac1ac6422b2)

```
declare @mytable as table(timestamp datetime,A int,B int,C int)

insert into @mytable values
('01-01-19 10:20',1,0,0),('01-01-19 15:30',0,0,1),
('01-01-19 22:50',0,1,0),('01-01-19 01:40',1,0,0)

;with cte as(
select 0 n 
union all
select n+10 from cte where n+10 <40)
select dateadd(mi,n,timestamp)[TIMESTAMP],t1.A,t1.B,T1.C 
from @mytable t1 cross join cte 
order by timestamp
```